# Dele remaining characters from every cell

Tags: shell, unix, sed

[image]

I have a file with multiple fields and multiple rows that looks like this:

```
111          768            359 

0|1:1:0,1,0  1|1:2:0,0,1    0|1:1:0,1,0 

1|1:2:0,0,1  0|1:1:0,1,0    0|0:0:1,0,0 

0|0:0:1,0,0  1|1:2:0,0,1    1|1:2:0,0,1
```

In every cell I want to keep only first three characters so that output looks like this:

```
111 768 359 

0|1 1|1 0|1 

1|1 0|1 0|0 

0|0 1|1 1|1
```

So basically what I want is to delete the remaining characters from each 'cell'. How can I do this? Hope the question is clear. If not please let me know and I will try to explain it more

Thanks.

Comment: The question is not clear. What's a "cell"? The first 3 characters in the 2nd |-separated field (if that's what a cell is) on the first row seem to be "1", ":", and "1" but that doesn't match your output of "1", " ", "1".

Comment: So I have added a picture of what my file looks like.

Comment: How does that picture help? Just tell us what it is you need with some concrete sample input, the expected output for that input and an explanation of why. Start by telling us what your fields are separated by - "|"s or ":"s or ","s or space chars or tabs or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk '{for (i=13;i<=NF;i++) $i=substr($i,1,3)} 1' file
111 768 359
0|1 1|1 0|1
1|1 0|1 0|0
0|0 1|1 1|1
```

**UPDATE** For the `12th row and 10th field onwards` requirement:

```
awk 'NR>10{for (i=13;i<=NF;i++) $i=substr($i,1,3)} 1' file
```

Comment: your code worked but it deleted very fourth character. I want to delete it from 12th row and 10th field onwards

Comment: But you didn't mention `12th row and 10th field` requirement in question.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. Is there a way to retain data until 10th row and 12th column as it is and have the output change to what your second code changes it to?

Comment: I have added a complete pic of my file. It has 7000 fields and 2400 such rows

Comment: ok check updated code. Question doesn't need pic but proper description of the problem.

Comment: @anubhava - +1, great job coming up with a solution. I still have no idea what the question was!

Comment: +1, `awk 'NR>10{for (i=13;i<=NF;i++) $i=substr($i,1,3)} 1'` is more concise.

Comment: Thanks glenn and @EdMorton, I have edited to make it concise as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '12,$s/(\S{3})\S*(\s)*/\1\2/10g' file
```

If you want to preserve white space:

```
sed -r '12,$s/(\S{3})\S*/\1/10g' file
```